# Symfony2 doctrine relations

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have 3 tables.

```
Product
+-----+-----------+
| id  |  name     |
+-----+-----------+
| 1   | Product 1 |
+-----+-----------+
| 2   | Product 2 |
+-----+-----------+

Categories
+-----+-----------+
| id  | name      |
+-----+-----------+
| 1   | cat 1     |
+-----+-----------+
| 2   | cat 2     |
+-----+-----------+

ProductCategories
+-----+------+------+
| id  | p_id | c_id |
+-----+------+------+
| 1   | 1    | 1    |
+-----+------+------+
| 2   | 1    | 2    |
+-----+------+------+
| 3   | 2    | 1    |
+-----+------+------+
```

Question:

1. Do I need to create a 3 Entity? Product, Categories and ProductCategories
2. How to make taking products by category id, they should contain information about their assigned categories?
3. Creating a new product and assigning a category from the List, category_id and product_id recorded in the table: product_categories?

Comment: Probably you need to first read this http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Answer (score 3):

You need only 2 entities, `Product` and `Category`, linked with ManyToMany mapping.

Read [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional), and you will found answers on your questions.